# Let $F$ be a finite subset of the natural numbers and consider the sum

Tags: summation

$$\sum(-1)^l\tag{1}$$

Define $F_{\text{even}} = \{n \in F : n\text{ is even}\}$  and  $F_{\text{odd}} = \{n \in F : n\text{ is odd}\}$

(a) Suppose that $\#F$ is odd. Show that $\#F_{\text{even}}\ne \#F_{\text{odd}}$
(b) Suppose that $\#F$ is odd. Show that $(1)$ is nonzero

Comment: Do you mean $(1)$ to be the $\sum\{(-1)^\ell:\ell\in F\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $(-1)^\ell$ is $1$ when $\ell$ is even and $-1$ when $\ell$ is odd. When you take the sum of all $(-1)^\ell$ with $\ell\in F$, you’re adding one for each even number in $F$ and subtracting $1$ for each odd number. Under what circumstances can the result of that operation possibly be $0$?

Comment: when #F$_{even}$ = #F$_{odd}$

Comment: @Felix: Exactly. And that’s the only time. Now just use the fact that $\#F=\#F_{\text{even}}+\#F_{\text{odd}}$ to do (a), and then use (a) to do (b).